# How to invoke Spring JPA function and return result in an object

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have function FUNC, in package PACKAGE_A, that I cannot modify. I would like to invoke this function from a Spring JPA repository and I do not know exactly how to do this.

Function:

```
FUNCTION FUNC(
    RESULT_COLUMN_A OUT NUMBER,
    RESULT_COLUMN_B OUT NUMBER,
    RESULT_COLUMN_C OUT VARCHAR
    ) RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3
    INTO RESULT_COLUMN_A, RESULT_COLUMN_B, RESULT_COLUMN_C 
    FROM DATABASE_TABLE;
    RETURN 0;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RETURN -1;
END;
```

Function has been modified for this question, it's not a working scenario but important thing is that function returns three columns.

My code until now:

```
@Repository
public class FunctionRepository{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public FuncResponse findFunctionResult() {
        SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withCatalogName("PACKAGE_A") //package name
                .withFunctionName("FUNC");
        //First parameter is function output parameter type.
        FuncResponse response = jdbcCall.executeFunction(FuncResponse.class);
        return response;
    }

    class FuncResult{
        @Column(name = "RESULT_COLUMN_A")
        String resultColumnA;
        String resultColumnB;
        String resultColumnC;
    }

}
```

When I try to run the code I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2033) ~[ojdbc11-21.3.0.0.jar:21.3.0.0.0]
```

Update:
I've updated by code with the following, my initial mistake was that the response was not the number, but a class. So updated code is this:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withCatalogName("PACKAGE_A") //package name
                .withFunctionName("FUNC")
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("RESULT_COLUMN_A ", Types.NUMERIC))
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("RESULT_COLUMN_B ", Types.NUMERIC))
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("RESULT_COLUMN_C ", Types.VARCHAR))
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();

        //First parameter is function output parameter type.
        Long response = jdbcCall.executeFunction(Long.class);
        if(response == 0){..}
```

Problem is that it's still failing with exception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.matchInParameterValuesWithCallParameters(CallMetaDataContext.java:610)
```

Comment: A function can have OUT or IN OUT parameters, but this is bad coding practice. A function should have a return value and no out parameter. If you need more than one value from a function you should use a procedure. In addition your missing the part in my code where I specify what the in parms and out parms.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing the in parms for the function. Here is a example from one of my projects. In addition you can only return one value per function but it looks like you are trying to return multiple values in your function above. You might want to double check that.

```
      /*this is at the top of my class. */
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
        static final String ORCL_SCHEMA = "scott";
        static final String ORCL_PKG = "BIGPACKAGE";

            @Override
            public String validateProgCode(String prog, String coas, Date trnsdate) {
                SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
             .withSchemaName(ORCL_SCHEMA)
             .withCatalogName(ORCL_PKG)
             .withFunctionName("F_VALIDATEPROGCODE")
             .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("L_PROG", OracleTypes.VARCHAR))
             .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("L_COAS", OracleTypes.VARCHAR))
             .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("TRNSDATE", OracleTypes.DATE));
        
                Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<>();
                inParams.put("L_PROG", prog);
                inParams.put("L_COAS", coas);
                inParams.put("TRNSDATE", trnsdate);
                String validInd = call.executeFunction(String.class, inParams);
                return validInd;
        }
```

this is a excerpt of the oracle function

```
 FUNCTION F_ValidateProgCode (L_PROG VARCHAR2, L_COAS VARCHAR2, trnsDate DATE) RETURN
    VARCHAR2 IS
    ....
  end;
```

Comment: No, I am returning one value, the number, but I have three OUT params. I've updated the question